# reset select value to zero from reset button

Tags: jquery, html

can someone help me and tell me what i'm doing wrong here... i want my reset button to reset button value to zero (0).

jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qr546/

html:

```
<select class="overtimehours" id="overtimehours" name="overtimehours[16523]">
<option value="2.75">2.75</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="0.25">0.25</option>
<option value="0.5">0.5</option>
<option value="0.75">0.75</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1.25">1.25</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="reset" value="reset"></input>
```

jquery:

```
$('#reset').on('click', function() {
    $('#overtimehours').val('0');
}
```

Comment: so actually your code is almost working fine, the real problem is your are missing ); at the end of your function (next to you didn't include jquery) see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qr546/15/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple remove the jquery code with below function.

```
$( "#reset" ).click(function() {
  $('#overtimehours').val(0);
});
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr546/4/)

Comment: caramba: The JSFiddle, at least, didn't actually include the jQuery library. So that's one reason why it wasn't working. I think it was also missing a close parenthesis at the end. See: https://api.monosnap.com/image/download?id=uUeC2Z5qw3slcus0USGwvsSoPzeNsb

Answer (score 4):

Rubyist's answer is correct, however this won't work on your current jsfiddle link, as jquery is not loaded there. You can add jquery from the frameworks & extensions pulldown list on the left side of the jsfiddle screen.

Comment: Yes Buddy, Jquery file is not added with jsfiddle, so link is not working. +1

Comment: Almost there (being allowed to comment, which this clearly should be), thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is not needed for this, HTML provides a `reset` button type. I had to also add the `selected` attribute to the `0`-valued option.

Here's an updated Fiddle using no JavaScript and only native elements: http://jsfiddle.net/y9z2v/